# Nginx Joomla frontend 550 internal and 404 error except frontpage

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404, joomla3.0

I get a 500 internal server error when i click a link on my frontpage, for instance: Create an account, or just a menu item i created myself.

Just installed Joomla on my VPS. Backend has no problems at all.

Error log:

> 2013/12/17 22:04:12 [error] 1974#0: *464 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internal redirect to "/index.php/index.php/component/users/", client: XX.XX.XXX.XX, server: my-domain.com, request: "GET /index.php/component/users/?view=remind HTTP/1.1", host: "my-domain.com", referrer: "http://my-domain.com/"

> 2013/12/17 22:04:12 [error] 1974#0: *465 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internal redirect to "/index.php/favicon.ico", client: XX.XX.XXX.XX, server: my-domain.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "my-domain.com"

I ran these commands after installing Joomla:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

(website is in `/var/www/my-domain.com/public`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri;
```

to:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri =404;
```

in order to get out of an infinte loop. No of course i get a 404 error, so that means it can't find the right file. I still don't understand how to solve that problem.